# Silverlight 4 :Listbox selection lost when pressing Ctrl + click

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a list-box with some items in it. When i click on one item its selected. 
But when i press Ctrl + click on same selected item then it will unselected and total no of selected items in list-box is zero.

So i want list-box should always have minimum one selected item.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `SelectionMode` property to "Multiple"?